# Solving differential Equations by substitution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

An example in my Differential Equations textbook shows how to solve the homogenous differential equation $$ (x^2+y^2)\,dx +(x^2-xy)\,dy=0 $$

by substituting $y$ with $ux$, which I am trying to understand. The book explains that the reason we do this is so that $dy$ will equal $u\,dx + x\,du$.

The answer says that after substitution, the equation becomes
$$(x-ux)\,dx + x(u\,dx + x\,du) = 0 $$ 
and then
$$ dx + x\,du = 0$$

My question is, how did it get to $dx+x\,du =0$? Is it a typo or am I missing something?

I think it should be $ x\,dx + x\,du$ and then $dx + du$ and then $x + u$ and eventually $x + y/x$.

However, the textbook says the answer is $x\ln(x)+y=cx$.

What am I missing?

Comment: How do you get $(x-ux)dx+x(udx+xdu)=0$?  I think this equation is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(x-ux)dx+x(udx+xdu)=0$$
Expanding both sides gives
$$xdx-uxdx+xudx+x^2du=0$$
$$xdx+x^2du=0$$
Assuming $x$ is non-zero:
$$dx+xdu=0$$

You forgot the extra factor of $x$ attached to the $du$.

Comment: You're right! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Write  $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x^2+y^2}{xy-x^2}$$

Then $$ x \frac{du}{dx}+u=\frac{1+u^2}{u-1} $$
This is a separable equation, which you can solve.